# 'For Each' loop keeps looping past 'If' condition

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, foreach

I am pulling emails from Outlook into Excel with VBA, comparing the subject line of the email with a range of cells on another sheet. I am using a For Each loop to achieve this but it seems as though when my if condition is met, it keeps going so it doesn't post the result that I want. It seems to loop through all of the cells in the range I have defined but then even when it meets my if condition, it keeps going and ends up being blank.

Here I am defining my ranges:

```
Dim rRng As Range, cel As Range
Set rRng = Sheet2.Range("A2:A1218")
```

Here is my For Each loop:

```
oRow = 1
    For iRow = 1 To Folder.Items.Count 'This loops through the inbox items.
        If VBA.DateValue(VBA.Now) - 1 <= VBA.DateValue(Folder.Items.Item(iRow).ReceivedTime) And VBA.DateValue(VBA.Now) > VBA.DateValue(Folder.Items.Item(iRow).ReceivedTime) Then 'This is checking that the emails were received within a certain time frame.
            For i = 0 To UBound(emails) 
                If StrComp(Folder.Items.Item(iRow).SenderEmailAddress, emails(i)) = 0 Then 'This is checking that the emails are coming from specific address', emails is an array of accepted address'.
                    For Each cel In rRng.Cells 'The beggining of my for each
                        If InStr(1, Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Subject, cel.Text) > 0 Then 'checking to see if my the content from one of the cells in the range is part of the subject from the emails.
                             ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 3) = cel.Value 'If it is part of the subject, take the value from the cell in the range where it matches, and put that value in another cell.
                        End If
                    Next cel
                    oRow = oRow + 1
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 1).Select
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 1) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).ReceivedTime
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 5) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).SenderEmailAddress
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 6) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Subject
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 7) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Body
                    'All of this above code is inserting data from the emails into cells.
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next iRow
```

oRow is a counter for rows in the excel sheet.

iRow is a counter for the email items.

Is there an even better approach?

Comment: It would help to describe in words exactly what the code is intended to do. It's unclear, but it seems like your inner `End If` is in the wrong place?

Comment: I added some more comments through out the code to try and explain it better.

Comment: Which `IF` is not doing what you expect?

Comment: If InStr(1, Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Subject, cel.Text). I want it to post the value if/when they match and then move on with the rest of the code but it seems as thought even after it finds the criteria to match the if condition, it keeps going through the cells

Answer (score 1):

EDIT2: still guessing a bit...

```
Dim itm As Object '<<< this makes your code more readable...
Dim rw as range

Set rw = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows(1)

For iRow = 1 To Folder.Items.Count

    Set itm = Folder.Items.Item(iRow)

    If Now - 1 <= itm.ReceivedTime Then
        For i = 0 To UBound(emails)
            If StrComp(itm.SenderEmailAddress, emails(i)) = 0 Then

                For Each cel In rRng.Cells
                    If InStr(1, itm.Subject, cel.Text) > 0 Then
                        rw.Cells(3).Value = cel.Value  
                        Exit For 'exit loop over cells
                    End If 'subject match
                Next cel
                'record the other details
                rw.Cells(1).Value = itm.ReceivedTime
                rw.Cells(5).Value = itm.SenderEmailAddress
                rw.Cells(6).Value = itm.Subject
                rw.Cells(7).Value = itm.Body
                Set rw = rw.Offset(1, 0)
                Exit For 'exit loop over emails
           End If 'email match
        Next i
    End If
Next iRow
```

Comment: It looks like that makes it so it doesn't loop at all after the first iteration.

Comment: Then maybe add a bit more code so it's easier to see what the issue is?  What are `iRow` and `oRow` for example?

Comment: This doesn't do exactly what I want it to, because I still want the code to move on even if cel.Text is not contained in itm.Subject. But I want cel.Text to be assigned to a cell IF it is within itm.Subject. My loop works, but even once it hits that if condition it keeps looping through the range or something. For example, First email has the subject "hello". that's not in my range so it can skip it. Second email has the subject "Lunch", lunch is in my range so I want cell (oRow,3) to be "Lunch"

Comment: What if there are multiple matches in the subject?  Just capture the first one and then list the rest of the mail details?

Comment: The values in my range are unique, there won't be a duplicate.

Comment: So as an example what is happening, it will have the email information in the row then I see the cursor vibrate as it loops through my range(it's large). I see oRow, 3 gets the value "lunch" then it disappears so it's as if even when the if condition is met, it keeps looping.

Comment: Re - duplicates: is there no chance more than one of those values will be found in the subject?

Comment: See my update - if this doesn't work for you then you will need to spell out exactly what the steps should be.

Comment: I actually was just about to comment and tell you I got it working. with this line "If InStr(1, itm.Subject, cel.Text) > 0 Then" it should be greater than 0 if the second string is found within the first one. But for some reason when I changed it to "If InStr(1, itm.Subject, cel.Text) > 1 Then" it made all the difference and it started working as I intended it to.. thank you for all your contribution.